# Why some of the elements cannot be selected by Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using Selenium webdriver for quite a while. Recently I came across this page: https://www.myagedcare.gov.au/service-finder

[image]

It seem very simple and I try to use id locator: bylocation

However, no matter how long I wait for the element to be ready by adding wait for some time, or wait for element to be ready like:

```
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("byname")))
            .click();
```

the element is never ready, and I always get error like "no such element: Unable to locate element:"

What might be going on? I've used locator for quite a while and I do not know how this can happen.

I am using chromedriver 2.30 and Chrome browser v.60.

A simple id locator like this in [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) does not give me any trouble. I tested it so that I do not think it's driver or browser issue.

### Logs

```
net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityWebDriverException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@id='bylocation']
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50'
System info: host: 'yun-PC', ip: '192.168.1.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='bylocation']"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.50)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.04 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath and let me know if it works,

`//div[@id='edit-search-by--2']//label[normalize-space(text())='Location']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']`

Also try waiting for visibility of element and not for element to be clickable.

**Edit:**

The above Xpath is perfect. Problem was that the element was located in a frame.
Below code will get you going with the click part:

```
     driver.get("https://www.myagedcare.gov.au/service-finder?tab=help-at-home");

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='content']")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='content']")));


    new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(text())='Location']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']")));

    WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(text())='Location']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']"));
    WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(text())='Name']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']"));

    location.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    name.click();

    driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

Click working video - https://www.screencast.com/t/0Fsw7gGZ

Comment: @thanks a lot for the frame reminder! totally forget it.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Radio Buttons` are inside `input` tags, instead of `id` use `xpath` locator as follows:

```
    WebDriverWait wait6 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement radio_name = wait6.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='byname']/input[@id='byname']")));
    radio_name.click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: it still does NOT work. i've waited 10 sec after page load already, then i use wait.until again as in post. no luck.

Comment: Updated my Answer. Let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: log attached. also tried your updated xpath. not working either.

Comment: @user1559625 Please see my updated Answer once again. :) It's different from what I saw in the logs. I updated twice in between. Thanks

Comment: i used your latest xpath. error log: 'Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='byname']/input[@id='byname']"}'